# VBA Copy range from excel to powerpoint

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I am trying to copy a specific range from excel and past it in pp as a picture. I have pieced together the following code from various online sources and continue to get a run time 91 error ( Object Variable or With block variable not set) when running PowerPointApp.WindowState = 2.

How can I fix this error, and avoid it in future?

first i successfully run

```
    Private Sub OpenPowerpoint()

        Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
        Set PPT = New PowerPoint.Application

        PPT.Visible = True
        PPT.Presentations.Open Filename:="C:\Users\aofarrell\Desktop\CYB\Weekly Pack Update - Template.pptx"
        PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Select

    End Sub
```

Then I attempt to run

```
 Private Sub CopyToPowerPoint()

            Dim rng As Range
            Dim PowerPointApp As Object
            Dim mySlide As Object
            Dim myShape As Object


        'Copy Range from Excel

            Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Triggers").Range("B6:Z33")

        'Copy Excel Range
            rng.Copy

        'Paste to PowerPoint and position
            PowerPointApp.WindowState = 2 'ERROR OCCURS HERE
            mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=0
            Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

        'Set position:
            myShape.Left = 20
            myShape.Top = 70
            myShape.Width = 675
            myShape.Height = 400

        'Clear The Clipboard
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

        End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm...  Well, first you need to define what type of `Object` your `PowerPointApp` is.  And what specific object your `mySlide` is.  Remember also that Local variables are destroyed at the end of the Sub/Function, so you may want some Module level variables/objects instead:

```
Option Explicit

Private PPT As PowerPoint.Application
Private PPT_pres As PowerPoint.Presentation

Private Sub OpenPowerpoint()
    Set PPT = New PowerPoint.Application

    PPT.Visible = True
    Set PPT_pres = PPT.Presentations.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\aofarrell\Desktop\CYB\Weekly Pack Update - Template.pptx")
    PPT_pres.Slides(2).Select
End Sub

Private Sub CopyToPowerPoint()
    If PPT Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If PPT_pres Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim mySlide As Object
    Dim myShape As Object

    Set mySlide = PPT_pres.Slides(2)

    'Copy Range from Excel

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Triggers").Range("B6:Z33")

    'Copy Excel Range
    rng.Copy

    'Paste to PowerPoint and position
    PPT.WindowState = 2
    mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=0
    Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

    'Set position:
    myShape.Left = 20
    myShape.Top = 70
    myShape.Width = 675
    myShape.Height = 400

    'Clear The Clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

End Sub
```

(Also: if I was copying as an Image from Excel to PowerPoint, I would usually use `Range.CopyPicture xlPrinter` rather than `Shapes.PasteSpecial` which changes the size of the image based on your screen resolution)